# Recursively using reflection to merge fields

Tags: java, optimization, performance

I'm using the Observer pattern to notify my UI that the object they're representing has changed. Also, I'm refreshing this object from the interwebs. Therefore, I'm ending up with two instances representing the same object. One with old values, one with refreshed values.

I have written this util class that recursively merges all fields from the refreshed instance into the original instance ([Full Gist](https://gist.github.com/nhaarman/b810cb9360ac260a5fab)). I am wondering if and how I can optimize this, and whether I've forgotten something.

The code works for some simple use cases.

```
public class MergeUtils {

    /**
     * Recursively merges the fields of the provider into the receiver.
     *
     * @param receiver the receiver instance.
     * @param provider the provider instance.
     */
    public static <T> void merge(final T receiver, final T provider) {
        Field[] fields = receiver.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            try {
                Object receiverObject = field.get(receiver);
                Object providerObject = field.get(provider);

                if (receiverObject == null || providerObject == null) {
                    /* One is null */
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    field.set(receiver, providerObject);
                } else if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Collection.class)) {
                    /* Collection field */
                    //noinspection rawtypes
                    mergeCollections((Collection) receiverObject, (Collection) providerObject);
                } else if (field.getType().isPrimitive() || field.getType().isEnum() || field.getType().equals(String.class)) {
                    /* Primitive, Enum or String field */
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    field.set(receiver, providerObject);
                } else { 
                    /* Mergeable field */
                    merge(receiverObject, providerObject);
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                /* Should not happen */
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Recursively merges the items in the providers collection into the receivers collection.
     * Receivers not present in providers will be removed, providers not present in receivers will be added.
     * If the item has a field called 'id', this field will be compared to match the items.
     *
     * @param receivers the collection containing the receiver instances.
     * @param providers the collection containing the provider instances.
     */
    public static <T> void mergeCollections(final Collection<T> receivers, final Collection<T> providers) {
        if (receivers.isEmpty() && providers.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        if (providers.isEmpty()) {
            receivers.clear();
            return;
        }

        if (receivers.isEmpty()) {
            receivers.addAll(providers);
            return;
        }

        Field idField;
        try {
            T t = providers.iterator().next();
            idField = t.getClass().getDeclaredField(ID);
            idField.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException ignored) {
            idField = null;
        }

        try {
            if (idField != null) {
                mergeCollectionsWithId(receivers, providers, idField);
            } else {
                mergeCollectionsSimple(receivers, providers);
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            /* Should not happen */
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Recursively merges the items in the collections for which the id's are equal.
     *
     * @param receivers the collection containing the receiver items.
     * @param providers the collection containing the provider items.
     * @param idField the id field.
     *
     * @throws IllegalAccessException if the id field is not accessible.
     */
    private static <T> void mergeCollectionsWithId(final Collection<T> receivers, final Iterable<T> providers, final Field idField) throws IllegalAccessException {
        /* Find a receiver for each provider */
        for (T provider : providers) {
            boolean found = false;
            for (T receiver : receivers) {
                if (idField.get(receiver).equals(idField.get(provider))) {
                    merge(receiver, provider);
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                receivers.add(provider);
            }
        }

        /* Remove receivers not in providers */
        for (Iterator<T> iterator = receivers.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            T receiver = iterator.next();
            boolean found = false;
            for (T provider : providers) {
                if (idField.get(receiver).equals(idField.get(provider))) {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Recursively merges the items in the collections one by one. Disregards equality.
     *
     * @param receivers the collection containing the receiver items.
     * @param providers the collection containing the provider items.
     */
    private static <T> void mergeCollectionsSimple(final Collection<T> receivers, final Iterable<T> providers) {
        Iterator<T> receiversIterator = receivers.iterator();
        Iterator<T> providersIterator = providers.iterator();
        while (receiversIterator.hasNext() && providersIterator.hasNext()) {
            merge(receiversIterator.next(), providersIterator.next());
        }

        /* Remove excessive receivers if present */
        while (receiversIterator.hasNext()) {
            receiversIterator.next();
            receiversIterator.remove();
        }

        /* Add residual providers to receivers if present */
        while (providersIterator.hasNext()) {
            receivers.add(providersIterator.next());
        }
    }
}
```

---

Some pseudo use case code:

```
MyObject myObject = retrieveFromWeb(1);
myView.setMyObject(myObject);
myObject.addObserver(myView);
// now refresh the data
MyObject myObject2 = retrieveFromWeb(1);
// instead of propagating the new object all the way to the view, use the merge util class:
MergeUtil.merge(myObject, myObject2);
myObject.notifyObservers();
```

Re-setting the new object to the view can lead to hassle (in Android for instance).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Could you provide some example use-cases of this code? I'm trying to see the bigger picture here...

Comment: As for as my knowledge goes you are ignoring the objects of super classes and inner classes.

Comment: The link to the Gist is 404. Also `idField = t.getClass().getDeclaredField(ID);`, should `ID` be a String `"ID"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if (receivers.isEmpty() && providers.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    if (providers.isEmpty()) {
        receivers.clear();
        return;
    }
```

You can remove the first if statement, it's not necessary. Clearing a list that has no elements is almost free anyway.

```
        for (T provider : providers) {
            if (idField.get(receiver).equals(idField.get(provider))) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
```

You could `break` out of the for loop here. No need to go over the rest of the providers once you've found a match.

```
field.getType()
```

You have a lot of those in your `merge` function. How about storing it in a temporary variable to increase readability?